# How to use if statement to upload txt or csv file in r

Tags: r, if-statement, shiny

I am uploading data but I want to upload text file or excel file using if statement. For example:

```
if(file == .txt){
 df <- read.table(inFile$datapath, header = input$header)
}
else{
 df <- read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = input$header, sep = 
input$sep, quote = input$quote)
}
```

Could anyone let me know what I need to use for if condition. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After uploading your file with a `fileInput` in shiny, you could read the filename extension (e.g. `some_file.txt` vs `some_file.csv`) to determine whether the uploaded file is a text file or csv.

Example:

```
if(grepl(inFile$name, ".txt", ignore.case=TRUE)) {
    df <- read.table(inFile$datapath, header = input$header)
} else if (grepl(inFile$name, ".csv", ignore.case=TRUE)) {
    df <- read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = input$header, sep = input$sep, quote = input$quote)
}
```

Type `?grepl` in Rconsole to see the functionality of `grep`.